# Hibernate - How to query using CLAUSES?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I was looking for the Hibernate Spring code to insert, remove update & select data. While reading over the tutorial, I dont understand how to get, update, insert, etc. data in Hibernate. I got a tutorial from here http://mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples

```
public static List getStockDailyRecordCriteria(Date startDate,Date endDate,
        Long volume,Session session){

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StockDailyRecord.class);
    if(startDate!=null){
        criteria.add(Expression.ge("date",startDate));
    }
    if(endDate!=null){
        criteria.add(Expression.le("date",endDate));
    }
    if(volume!=null){
        criteria.add(Expression.ge("volume",volume));
    }
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("date"));

    return criteria.list();
  }
```

Here it seems to be selecting data, but there is not SELECT query. How do we know that it is retrieving the data from the database ?

I also got this code from here http://codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration which seems to get the data but I dont understand where is the table name, & query used ?

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public List<User> list() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(User.class)
                .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();

        return listUser;
    }
```

What to do to update, delete, insert data in the database ?
How to use condition like WHERE, ORDER BY, GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT, etc to get, delete, update, insert data ?

Comment: But you just posted the same question two minutes ago.

Comment: @BranislavLazic, Made the question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us say that class StockDailyRecord is mapped to table **stockdailyrecord** in the database.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StockDailyRecord.class);
```

here just like a select statement , this Criteria act as select * from stockdailyrecord

then some conditions are added to this criteria

```
criteria.add(Expression.ge("date",startDate));
```

here like where date >= startDate

```
criteria.add(Expression.le("date",endDate));
```

here like where date <= endDate

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("date"));
```

To sort records in ascending order
 ORDERBY **criteria.addOrder** , GROUP BY **criteria.add(Projections.groupProperty("someColumn"))**, COUNT **criteria.add(Projections.count("someColumn"))**

see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm) link it will help

Comment: Nice information! What about Update, delete, & Insert queries. How do they get executed ? Also you used `ge` & `le` but the link you provided, they used `gt` & `lt` for > & <.

Comment: `gt `is > & `lt `is < , to **insert** you can create your object then `session.save(myObj)` ,for deleting , updating use HQL which is the best option, I think, Criteria's main purpose is for only retrieving the data [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) to sum it up